# Different answer when converting a Double to an Int - Java vs .Net

Tags: java, .net, rounding

In C# if I want to convert a double (1.71472) to an int then I get the answer 2.  If I do this in Java using intValue() method, I get 1 as the answer.

Does Java round down on conversions?

Why do the Java API docs have such scant information about their classes i.e.

> Returns the value of the specified
>   number as an int. This may involve
>   rounding or truncation.

A bit more info about the rounding would have been helpful!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java rounds toward zero when narrowing from a floating point to an integer type—and so does C#, when you use the casting conversion. It's `Convert.ToInt32` that rounds:

```
double d = 1.71472;
int x = (int) d; // x = 1
int y = Convert.ToInt32(d); // y = 2
```

Details can be found in the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html). Note that while the documentation cited in `Number` leaves options open for subclasses, the documentation on the concrete boxing types, like [`Double`,](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) is explicit about the implementation:

> Returns the value of this Double as an
>   int (by casting to type int).

When using [`BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), you can specify one of eight different rounding policies.

Answer (score 7):

Java rounds toward zero when narrowing from a floating point to an integer type.

There's more documentation about the general rules in the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html). Note that while the documentation in `Number` leaves options open for subclasses, the documentation on the concrete boxing types is more explicit:

> Returns the value of this Double as an
>   int (by casting to type int).

When using [BigDecimal](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), you can specify one of eight different rounding policies.

Answer (score 3):

Jon Skeet is correct, but something else to watch for is that .NET uses [Banker's Rounding](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding.aspx) as its rounding algorithm.  When you're halfway between round towards the even integer.

Comment: Actually, it's even worse than that. .NET uses banker's rounding in most situations, but not all (format strings are one case where common rounding is used). You also have the ability to change the rounding method used in .NET 2.0 and later.