# Strange double rounding issue

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding

I came across the following silly function [here](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=338926&start=0&msRange=15):

```
public static String findOutWhatLifeIsAllAbout() {
    int meaning = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 300; k++) {
          for (int m = 0; m < 7000; m++) {
            meaning += Math.random() + 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return String.valueOf(meaning).replaceAll("0*$", "");
}
```

In summary, the expected result is a string "42", since Math.random() returns doubles "greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0".  In practice, running on an i5 under Ubuntu the resulting strings are similar to "420000011", "420000008"!  (meaning sometimes Math.random()'s result is getting *rounded up*!

To get a grip on what sorts of double values would cause Math.random()'s result to somehow *round* to 1, I tried this function instead, expecting to see some examples.

```
public static String findOutWhatLifeIsAllAboutAltered() {
    int meaning = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 300; k++) {
          for (int m = 0; m < 7000; m++) {
            double randomResult = Math.random();
            int converted = randomResult;

            if (converted > 0) {
                System.out.println("Misbehaving double = " + randomResult);
            }

            meaning += converted + 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return String.valueOf(meaning).replaceAll("0*$", "");
}
```

However this formulation always returns "42"!  Can anyone offer insight about why the behavior changes in the altered function?  Thanks.

Furthermore why does Java let the original function compile at all?  Shouldn't there be a loss-of-precision error at the `+=` call?

*edit* posted the code I wanted you all to see - the "original" version wasn't supposed to have a cast.

Comment: What version of Java are you compiling this with? I've tested this out and it gives the correct answer using Java 1.6.

Comment: Also, on my system (Java 1.6 on OS X) both functions return `"42"`.

Comment: "corrected" the first example.  There wasn't supposed to be a cast to int.  That code will compile and demonstrate the unexpected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small but important difference between the code in the link and the code originally posted here,

```
meaning += Math.random() + 1;    // link
```

vs.

```
meaning += (int)Math.random() + 1;  // StackOverflow
```

If the code posted here prints out anything but 42, it's a serious bug.

Here, the result of `Math.random()` is explicitly cast to `int`, that *must* result in 0, then 1 is added, resulting in 1, which then is added to `meaning`.

The code in the linked post, however performs an implicit cast to `int` after adding the result of `Math.random()` to 1 and that to `meaning`, basically

```
meaning = (int)(Math.random() + (double)1 + (double)meaning);
```

Now, if the result of `Math.random()` is close enough to 1.0, it occasionally happens that the result of the `double` addition is rounded up, so producing a final result slightly larger than immediately expected.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't there be a loss-of-precision error at the += call?

**No.** In the first case, you're explicitly casting the value returned by `Math.random()` to an `int`. In the second case, `meaning`, `converted`, and `1` are all integers.

---

There is, however, a possible loss-of-precision at this line:

```
int converted = randomResult;
```

http://ideone.com/1ZTDi

Comment: I think he means the loss of precision error should come from that line, not necessarily that operation - notably the (int) cast from the double returned by Math.random() would loose precision ... it should cause all values to be 0.

Comment: Explicitly casting from `double` to `int` will never not-compile due to possible loss of precision.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a loss of precision error at all because they're all ints in this example - you're not actually adding any doubles!

The only line where you could be you're casting the result of `Math.random()` to an int - so you're still just adding two ints together.

However, even if you were adding doubles to an int then there still wouldn't be because the JLS defines an implicit cast for these types of operators:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

Source:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2

Comment: I believe he means loss of precision at this line: meaning += (int)Math.random() + 1;

Comment: Well considering the cast is there, it's still 2 ints that he's adding together!

Comment: The adding isn't causing loss of precision (I don't think he's suggesting that either) - the cast is though.

Answer (score 0):

Loss of precision could only come on these lines as you're doing type conversion:

```
double randomResult = Math.random();
int converted = randomResult;
```

As **Math.random()** returns an **double** which is between **0.0** inclusive and **1.0** exclusive, the variable **converted** will only ever contain 0 as it's converted to an **int**.

For more on the casting from a double > int, see here: [Different answer when converting a Double to an Int - Java vs .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300055/different-answer-when-converting-a-double-to-an-int-java-vs-net)

I've tried your original program on a Java 6 system running on Mac OS X (Lion) and it only outputs 42. Which JRE/JDK are you using?